# Silverlight: Uninstalling Out-of-Browser app does not remove "..\Silverlight\OutOfBrowser\index" file

Tags: silverlight, out-of-browser

For better or worse, I have another application which scans that directory as a way to see if the silverlight application is installed out of browser or not.
Even when uninstalling the application though, it leaves that file behind.
Is there a way to configure the SL application to remove that file when uninstalled?

Or is there a more efficient way to see if the SL OOB application is installed or not?